# How to easily select a link text in a browser without activating the link

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, links, mouse-click, vivaldi

I'm used to select text by double (or triple) click to select whole word (paragraph).

---

[image: double/triple click text selection example]

---

But this doesn't work when the word or the paragraph is a link. The link is activated by first click. Is there some (standard) trick to temporarily disable links?

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and their combinations as modifiers, but with no success.

Comment: On Mac just right click the link. That doesn't seem to work in Windows though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply holding down the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> and double or tripling clicking on links seems to be working on Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Also double or triple clicking on the white space in the beginning or end of the link should do the trick. This at least works for hyperlinks.

[You can try it for yourself here](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Yes, left alt seems to be working in major browsers. In my Vivaldi it downloads the link target (but double/triple click works as desired).

Comment: Several Linux desktops will move the window when holding Alt, even on simple click (I wish they would only try to move when actually dragging, as it breaks mouse shortcuts in many apps), preventing text selection. In KDE you can change the modifier to e.g. Meta key, though.

Comment: ... and this other comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/521423/how-can-i-disable-altclick-window-dragging gave me the trick: hold Super (Meta) + Alt and click to bypass window drag! Now I can highlight the hyperlink text too!